dopamine_RL produces RuntimeError: Cannot sample a batch with fewer than stack size
I am using the below self contained example but getting this error:
RuntimeError: Cannot sample a batch with fewer than stack size (1) + update_horizon (1) transitions.
  In call to configurable 'WrappedReplayBuffer' (<class 'dopamine.replay_memory.circular_replay_buffer.WrappedReplayBuffer'>)

I am not quite sure what causes the eror:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gym
import dopamine
import logging  # Add this line
from dopamine.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
from dopamine.replay_memory import circular_replay_buffer
from dopamine.colab import utils as colab_utils
import tensorflow as tf
import os

# Create your environment
class CustomEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super(CustomEnv, self).__init__()
        self.df = df
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(1)  # Action space (predict F_1_d_returns)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)  # State space (1_d_returns, 2_d_returns)
        self.current_step = 0

    def reset(self):
        # Reset the environment to initial state
        self.current_step = 0
        self.state = self.df.iloc[self.current_step, 1:3].values  # Start with first row's 1_d_returns and 2_d_returns
        return self.state

    def step(self, action):
        # Take an action (not relevant here as we are predicting)
        self.current_step += 1
        done = self.current_step >= len(self.df) - 1
        if done:
            next_state = self.state
        else:
            next_state = self.df.iloc[self.current_step, 1:3].values
        reward = 0  # No reward for predicting
        info = {}   # Additional information (if needed)
        return next_state, reward, done, info

# Create your environment

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'F_1_d_returns': [-0.038076, 0.083333, 0.060577, -0.013599, -0.020221],
    '1_d_returns': [-0.062030, -0.038076, 0.083333, 0.060577, -0.013599],
    '2_d_returns': [-0.133681, -0.097744, 0.042084, 0.148958, 0.046154]
})

env = CustomEnv(df)

# Set up logging
LOG_PATH = '/tmp/dopamine/logs'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create a TensorFlow session
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

# Set up a replay buffer


# Set up a replay buffer with increased capacity
replay_buffer = circular_replay_buffer.WrappedReplayBuffer(
    observation_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape,
    stack_size=1,
    replay_capacity=100000)  # Increased capacity


# Create the agent
# Create the agent with decreased min replay history
# Create the agent with a higher min replay history
agent = dqn_agent.DQNAgent(
    sess,
    num_actions=env.action_space.n,
    observation_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape,
    observation_dtype=tf.float32,
    stack_size=1,
    network='dqn',
    gamma=0.99,
    update_horizon=1,
    min_replay_history=1000,  # Increase min replay history
    update_period=4,
    target_update_period=100,
    epsilon_fn=lambda x: 0.1)

# Create a checkpoint directory
checkpoint_dir = os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'checkpoints')
checkpoint_file_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'ckpt')
if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
    os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)

# Create a logger
logger = colab_utils.Logger(LOG_PATH)

# Initialize variables
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

# Train the agent
for episode in range(100):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = agent.begin_episode(obs)
        next_obs, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        agent.end_episode(reward)
        replay_buffer.add(obs, action, reward, next_obs, done)
        obs = next_obs

        if len(replay_buffer) >= agent.min_replay_history:
            experience = replay_buffer.sample(1)
            agent.step(experience)

    if episode % 10 == 0:
        logger.scalar_summary('Return', reward, step=episode)

# Save the final checkpoint
checkpoint_path = agent._saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file_prefix)
print('Final checkpoint saved at: %s' % checkpoint_path)

